# cgilua: web page not refreshed every time

Tags: php, nginx, lua, cgi

I'm using cgilua on a nginx server and my problem is when I put some lua code in my pages, the content seems to be cached.

For example

```
<!-- index.lp -->
<%= math.random(100000) %>
```

Displays the same value many times if I refresh the page, this does not happen with a PHP page. My problem is very embarassing when using POST data because the page is loaded randomly in its cache.

Is there specific HTTP headers to set? Why is it working with php?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calling CGILua? Post your config on paste bin and add a link

Comment: --> http://pastebin.com/Bt4AdunD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cgilua.fcgi, there was this line:

```
reload = false,           -- if you want to reload the application on every request
```

I set it to true and my problem seems to not appear again.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that the random number generator is not initialized, and therefore returning the same number every time. Try running `math.randomseed(os.time())` before calling `math.random()`.